# Creating a filename which can be used by everyone with different paths

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with creating a PDF with a button in Excel (VBA).

We have this code:

```
Sub pdf_drucken2()
ChDir "C:\Users\Name"
Worksheets("LaptopReport").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=x1TypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Name\test213.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
End Sub
```

I would like to create this PDF on every computer. When I send this Excel Sheet to someone, he should be able to create the PDF as well. So is there a way I can create a PDF without specifying a path like "C:\Users\Name\test.pdf"?

Comment: You could use Excel's [file dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to prompt the user for a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables to get the username:

```
Filename:= "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & "\Desktop\test213.pdf"
```